# Relay for ESP8266 using BC548

Tags: pcb, diodes, relay, esp8266, esp32

I'm working on a diy pcb relay for one of my project which uses ESP8266 as a microcontroller. For switching relay I'm using bc548 npn transistor but yet I'm not sure it'll completely turn on at 3.3v. I checked datasheet but I didn't find anything about turning on bc548 at low voltage.

Below is my schema:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should check the relay coil current. The 5V relays I'm using take 70m1, so I'll use that.

Then check the transistor datasheet for BC548:

- Max Collector Current (DC) IC 100 mA, so 70mA is OK.

Check saturation:

- VCE(sat) Collector−Emitter Saturation Voltage for IC=100mA, IB=5mA: typ 250mV max 600mV

This means at Ic close to 100mA, you can expect a current gain around 20 (Ib=5mA) and VceSat will be at most 0.6V so the relay will be powered by 4.4V instead of 5V, which is OK.

> I checked datasheet but I didn't find anything about turning on bc548 at low voltage.

It's not a MOSFET, it's a bipolar transistor, so what matters is base current not voltage. From the saturation spec above you should aim for 5mA base current. VbeSat is 0.9V, so if your ESP8266 outputs 3.3V, this means voltage drop on the base resistor will be 3.3-0.9=2.4V ; to get 5mA a 470 ohm base resistor is alright.

So R3 should be 330 to 470 ohms.

Note R1 is too low, since it sets LED current to about 30mA which is too high for a 5mm red LED, they're usually limited to 20mA. I'd recommend 470 ohms too. Modern LEDs are usually way too bright at 20mA anyway.